# Difference Basic Authorization between Postman and JQUERY AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have done the following steps:

First send the request without header basic Authorization.
Result is 'Authentication required'. So the connection to the Icecast server is working!

Then I try to switch on Authorization in 3 different ways:
The 3 ways are comment out in the below code.

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.xyz.eu:8000/admin/",    //the page containing php script
// way 1: use use username and password a
//              username: uName,
//              password: pWord

// way 2: sendbefore
/*              beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + bAuth); 
                }*/
// way 3: headers
/*              headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Basic ........"
                }/*

            })
            .done(function(){
                alert('done');
            })
            .always(function(xhr, status, error){
                alert("Failed XHR: " + JSON.stringify(xhr) + " Status: " + status + " Error: " + error);
            })
```

For the wax 3, I used the header settings from `Postman`.
The result is always the same: `Failed XHR: {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"} Status: error Error:`

The strange thing is, if I do the same request with `Postman` it works fine!

All other headers in `Postman` are switched off, so there should be no difference.

So what could be the difference between `Postman` and the ajax call?
Is there anythig missing?

**Edit 2023-02-17**

I also found, that `Postman`and a`Ajax` are sending difference headers. So added the additional headers to `Postman` und `Postman` is still working!

So there it must be somethig else, why `Ajax` isn't working with `Icecast`!

How can I check it?

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask]. Before you describe what you've attempted, describe the _problem_ you're trying to solve.

Comment: You should provide more information about the headers sent from the browser and from Postman.
Also, check from DevTools > Network tab if you find any error message on the failed XHR call (CORS errors? Request blocked from e.g. Adblock?).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `CORS Failed`!

So finally, I figured out, that due to browser security and that I have no possibilty to enable `CORS` on `Icecast`, there is not possible to do it inside the browser (Javascript or JQuery)!

So I have to do a workaround. I use `Ajax` to send back a `POST` to my own `PHP script` and do it there with `Curl`. That works fine.